# Values of NSArray does not print

Tags: objective-c

```
NSArray *headerDataArrays =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:((FNPayment *)fnPayment), nil];
NSLog(@"count====%d", headerDataArrays.count); // 1
```

But I am not unable to print array value. Also total array. I have tried like bellow. 

`NSLog(@"paymentMethod=== %@", [headerDataArrays objectAtIndex:2]);`

Comment: What is it logging now?

Comment: why you logging objectAtIndex 2 if the array count is only 1.

Comment: i think it should crash, because headerArray has one object only. [headerDataArrays objectAtIndex:0] will work here.

Comment: Check your input data again. How many element are there in your array?

Comment: @pawan, when [headerDataArrays objectAtIndex:0] then it is not crashing. Now how I can retrieve the value.

Comment: @gsl you can print this " [headerDataArrays objectAtIndex:0]" in nslog to get the object. or you can print the value  write the property name you want to access here . like  (FNPayment*)[headerDataArrays objectAtIndex:0].paymentValue).

Answer (score 1):

The array size in this case is 1 only, so index 2 (and even index 1) would be out of the bounds, because indexes are in the interval [0..[array count] - 1] in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined a description method for your `FNPayment` class?

```
- (NSString *)description {
     NSString *descriptionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blah %@; blah blah: %@;", self.b, self.bb];
     return descriptionString;

}
```

Objective C does not know what to print for your class, but it should print the address at the least.